# Calling method on an object that is a private member of a class

Tags: c++, object, methods, private

Say I have a class called ListofArrays, and one of its private members is an object (say, a vector called myVector) How would I access a method of that vector object? Say the vector has a method that returns its pointer to head.

> ListofArrays a;

Which of the following works? Why? Thanks!

> a.myVector.head()
>
> a.head()

Comment: did you try it first?

Comment: I am not in a position to currently

Answer (score 1):

`a.myVector().head()` will not work because `myVector` is private to the outside world, only code inside of `ListofArrays` (or `friend`s of `ListofArrays`) can access it.

`a.head()` will work only if `ListofArrays` exposes its own public `head()` method, eg:

```
class ListofArrays
{
private:
    vector myVector;

public:
    Type head();
};

Type ListofArrays::head()
{
    return myVector.head();
}
```